# Getting all questions that do not necessarily have two different tags using SEDE

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

So I am trying to use SEDE to get a table of questions that contain two separate tags (but do not necessarily have both) from Puzzling Stack Exchange to find puzzles that I might be able to solve. After I managed to fix my previous code, I was able to include the other tag that I am trying to restrict the list of questions to.

However, I am having a hard time writing the code so that I can retrieve all of the questions that either only have one or both of the tags. Instead, I am only able to retrieve the questions that have both.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/1822069/2214584/list-of-questions-on-p-se-with-score-0score10-and-with-two-tags-finally-works) is the code that I have managed to come up with (after reading a few more tutorials):

```
SELECT p.Title, p.Id, p.Score, p.ViewCount, u.DisplayName, p.Tags
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.Id=p.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.id = pt.TagId
INNER JOIN PostTags pt1 ON p.Id=pt1.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags t1 ON t1.Id = pt1.TagId
WHERE p.PostId=1
AND (t.TagName=##tagName:string?logical-deduction##)
AND (t1.TagName=##tagName:string?grid-deduction##)
AND p.Score <=10
AND p.Score >=0
AND p.AcceptedAnswerId is null
ORDER BY p.Score DESC
```

which only seems to return questions that contain both tags (along with whatever other tags they have) while also abiding by the other restrictions.

My question is: Why is it only returning questions with both of the tags, and how can I make it so the query also returns the questions that only have one of the following tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would personally solve the problem:

```
SELECT p.Title, p.Id, p.Score, p.ViewCount, u.DisplayName, p.Tags
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.Id=pt.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.id = pt.TagId
WHERE p.PostTypeId=1
AND (t.TagName=##tagName:string?logical-deduction## OR t.TagName=##tagName:string?grid-deduction##)
AND p.Score <=10
AND p.Score >=0
AND p.AcceptedAnswerId is null
ORDER BY p.Score DESC
```

Noted differences: got rid of duplicate joins `t1` `pt1`, this was causing your query to not work as expected. I added a search on `p.Tags` so if, in the future, you want to get rid of forcing the `t.TagName` to be either `grid-deduction` or `logical-deduction`, you could comment out that line, uncomment out the other, and this would just leave `p.Tags` being searched. This would cause the query to not care about the main tag and just the additional tags.

If you wanted to **ONLY** return values that have grid or logical (but not both) you could use the following where clause:

```
AND (
    (p.Tags LIKE '%logical-deduction%' AND p.Tags NOT LIKE '%grid-deduction%') OR
    (p.Tags LIKE '%grid-deduction%' AND p.Tags NOT LIKE '%logical-deduction%')
)
```

Comment: FWIW, `AND (p.Tags LIKE '%logical-deduction%' OR p.Tags LIKE '%grid-deduction%')` actually returns all questions *and answers* for the two tags - although appearing as duplicates of the question info.

Comment: Interesting, I probably should've looked more into the schema... Thank you for the info ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IN` on the tag name, and put the tag check inside an `EXISTS` to prevent a cartesian product.

```sql
SELECT
  p.Title,
  p.Id,
  p.Score,
  p.ViewCount,
  u.DisplayName,
  p.Tags
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
WHERE p.PostTypeId=1
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM PostTags pt
    INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.id = pt.TagId
    WHERE p.Id = pt.PostId
      AND t.TagName IN (
        ##tagName:string?logical-deduction##,
        ##tagName1:string?grid-deduction##
      )
  )
  AND p.Score <=10
  AND p.Score >=0
  AND p.AcceptedAnswerId is null
ORDER BY
  p.Score DESC;
```

[**SEDE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/edit/1822450)